# How to prove that a given set is recursively enumerable?

Tags: computability

I was given a set
$$
A = \{x \mid W_x \, \text{contains at least one prime number}\}
$$
where $W_x = \{y\mid \phi_x(y) \downarrow \}$ is the Dom of the function $\phi_x$

$\downarrow$ means that the function converges or halts.

Any hints on what to prove first?
I am not even sure how to tackle this kind of problem as it doesn't look like anything we have solved during the lessons so far.

Comment: Do you mean computably enumerable?

Comment: @O.Peters yes I made a mistake in the usage of the terms (not studying in English, which makes translating somewhat tricky). I meant recursively enumerable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give the answer in Turing machines.
First, build a Turing machine R(x, y, z) with 3 inputs that does the following

1. Check if x is a syntactically valid encoding of a Turing machine.
2. Check if y encodes a number and the number is prime.
3. Check if z is a valid encoding describing a run of the TM x on input y that stops and accepts.
   If all steps succeed, R stops and accepts.  Else rejects.
   R is a deterministic TM that halts on all inputs - therefore computable.
   A is the set $\{x:\exists y \exists z R(x,y,z)\}$ so is computably enumerable.
   Now translate to recursive functions.

Comment: Am I correct to assume, that we can say that $x \in A \Leftrightarrow \exists y \exists z ( \text{y is prime} \wedge \phi_{f(y)}(x) \downarrow \, \text{is reachable in z steps})$? Or did I misunderstand how am I supposed to translate?

Comment: I don't know what the $f$ in your notation is.  You need something called Kleene's T predicate to define R in recursive function theory.  You also need a function fo check primality which can be done which basic building blocks of primitive recursion.  That's why I prefer Turing machines which are a more tractable model of conputation.

Comment: z is not the number of steps in a computation of x on input y.  It's a description of a run of a computation of x on input y.  That' what Kleene's T is for.